# Test agent cannot connect to Test controller on Windows Azure

Tags: azure-worker-roles, azure-connect

I wanted to create a Test rig on cloud. I have created a windows azure hosted service that installs Test Controller and configures it with on premise DB. I have created another hosted service that installs Test Agent. I have enabled Virtual network in the Azure service by providing Activation token taken from azure portal. I also created a Azure Connect Group in which I added my local endpoint(On Premise DB) and windows azure roles( Test Controller rand Test Agent). When I deploy this on azure I am facing problem of Test Agent connectivity with Test Controller.

Test Controller can ping to my on premise DB machine and vice versa. But my test controller machine cannot ping test agent machine or vice versa on cloud.

I have ensured following things on test Controller

```
User testagent is part of group TeamTestAgentService
User testagent is also administrator on TestController hosted service.
Firewall exceptions have been added
```

If I try to ping two azure machines I cannot do that. By default azure has ping disabled so I added following firewall rule

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMPv6" dir=in action=allow enable=yes protocol=icmpv6

but it still does not work. I think if these two machines will be able to ping each other the problem of test agent connectivity to test controller on cloud will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/rlfh/

It won’t work as you have it now. The controller and agents have to be in different roles, but also the controller you need to install Azure Connect as an endpoint– not enabled as a role. So, you want to configure the Controller manually, then it should show up so you can add it to the Connect From list. Leave the agents as they are(azure connect as a role) and then it should work. The Roles in the Connect TO: part won’t be allowed to intercommunicate, though an endpoint can – since they have the option you selected to allow this.

My problem was solved when I manually installed Azure Connect endpoint from azure portal on the controller machine instead of enabling it as a Role in Virtual network.